# Enable field inside Manage Display from a .yml file

Tags: installation-profiles, 8

When I create a field `field.field.node.custom.body.yml` in my custom module with the following code:

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.storage.node.body
    - node.type.customblog
  module:
    - text
id: node.customblog.body
field_name: body
entity_type: node
bundle: customblog
label: Body
description: ''
required: false
translatable: true
default_value: {  }
default_value_callback: ''
settings:
  display_summary: true
field_type: text_with_summary
```

The *Body* field is created and added to the appropriate CT when installed, but is set as disabled in the manage display. This seems to be default behavior. I would like the field to be enabled as the module is installed through the use of `.yml` files, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single config entity per *entity_type*, *bundle* and *view/form mode*. If you fully control that, then you can provide those config entities, if you just add a single field to something existing, you need to use the API to add your fields configuration to it.

See [`core.entity_form_display.node.article.default.yml`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!profiles!standard!config!install!core.entity_form_display.node.article.default.yml/8.2.x) in standard.profile and various others for examples.